# $(x,y)$ with operations $(x,y)+(x´,y´)=(x+x´+1,y+y´+1)$ and $k(x,y)=(kx,ky)$ ex

Tags: linear-algebra

> The set of all pairs of real numbers $(x,y)$ with the operations $$(x,y)+(x´,y´)=(x+x´+1,y+y´+1)\quad \text{and} \\k(x,y)=(kx,ky).$$ Determine if this set is a vector space.

If I try to check out **axiom 5** that states 
$$u+(-u)=0$$ 
I get 
$$(x,y)-(x,y)
\\=(x,y)+(-x,-y)
\\=(x-x+1,y-y+1)
\\=(1,1)$$ 
Since 
$$(1,1)\neq 0$$ 
I am led to conclude the axiom 5 is not satisfied, however in the solution there´s no mention of the 5 axiom failure.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Could you state what you are working on?

Comment: @Bye_World $k(1,1)\ne (1,1)$ is wrong acoording to the assumption k(x,y)=(kx,ky). Anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: But my problem is that the  solution does not point out axiom 5 failure not even 4) that states $u+0=0+u=u$  Do you think the solution is incomplete?

Comment: Your book/ homework has not given you enough information.  In addition to giving you definitions of $+$ and $\cdot$, in specifying this structured set they should have also told you which vector they're making $\mathbf 0$ (and ideally -- though we could just figure it out ourselves -- what $-\mathbf v$ is for a given $\mathbf v$).  In this case, they *might* mean for the zero of the set to be $$\mathbf 0 = (-1,-1)$$ and then we can see that for any $\mathbf v$, the inverse is $$-\mathbf v = (-x-2,-y-2)$$

Comment: However, even though axioms $(4)$ and $(5)$ hold with these definitions, this structured set still isn't a vector space with these definitions as it fails some of the other axioms.  For instance, distributivity doesn't hold because if it did then $$(0,0) = 0(x,y) = (0+0)(x,y) = 0(x,y)+0(x,y) = (0,0)+(0,0) = (1,1)$$

Comment: Which axioms does you solution sheet say fail, out of curiosity?

Comment: 7) $k(u+v)=ku+kv$ and 8) $(k+l)u=ku+lu$ @Bye_World

Comment: OK.  Well that seems to support my conjecture as to what the zero vector and inverse are supposed to be in this set then.

Comment: So the zero vector would be $(1,1)$ right?

Comment: No.  $(1,1)$ would make axiom 4 fail.  $\mathbf 0 = (-1,-1)$ makes axiom 4 hold and for any $\mathbf v = (x,y)$ defining $-\mathbf v=(-x-2,-y-2)$ makes axiom 5 hold.